# Static files won't load when using Vercel

Tags: python, django, vercel

When I host my project locally, everything works. My stylesheet loads without a problem, however when I deploy it to Vercel neither the admin static files nor my own load.
Here is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')
MEDIA_URLS ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and my vercel.json:

```
{
    "builds": [{
        "src": "social/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    },
    {
        "src": "build_files.sh",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build",
        "config": { "distDir": "staticfiles_build" }
    }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "social/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I have run the collect static command and I have tried changing the root and the url, but I am very lost and do not fully understand why it will not work.

Comment: have you ran `python manage.py collectstatic` before you starting the server

Comment: Did you set up static file serving, separately from Django? When testing locally with `DEBUG=True`, runserver will for dev convenience serve static files for you, but as soon as `DEBUG=False` it won't by default. It's up to you to set up static file serving as per their documentation it's not a feature supported for production. If you are still running `runserver` without DEBUG mode, you can test this by adding the [--insecure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure) flag which will once again host those files.

Comment: How did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove this part

```
{
  "src": "/static/(.*)",
   "dest": "/static/$1"
},
```

and use whitenoise instead from this [link](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is more production ready and works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem.
Probably you need to specify the output directory for your static files:

```
{
    "builds": [{
        "src": "social/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    },
    {
        "src": "build_files.sh",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build",
        "config": { "distDir": "staticfiles_build" }
    }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "social/wsgi.py"
        }
    ],

    "outputDirectory": "staticfiles_build"
}
```